# Pull records from database giving preference to records with higher vote count

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm, codeigniter

I have a client that I'm developing a video site for. He is wanting to pull 2 videos from the database to show the front end user to vote on.

The videos table has a "votes" field. He is wanting to pull the videos randomly, but give higher preference to videos with higher vote counts. Some kind of algorithm where the votes are given preference but not just a straight up "highest voted 2 videos get pulled".

Any ideas?

Heres what my videos table looks like:

```
$data[] = array(
        'id' => $row->id,
        'filename' => $row->filename,
        'added' => $row->added,
        'userId' => $row->userId,
        'contestId' => $row->contestId,
        'complete' => $row->complete,
        'ended' => $row->ended,
        'votes' => $row->votes
    );
```

Comment: That's what your data array looks like. Your videos table (I'm guessing) looks a little different.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a nicely balanced sum of `ORDER BY votes * ($offset + rand()) DESC`, where offset balances the randomisation. If offset is 0, it is mostly random, if offset is 1 or higher, the unvoted videos will never get shown.

You can try the resulting videos in a dry run a few times and look if you like it. ;-)

EDIT:

The answer depends on the range and distribution of votes which will be in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following...

```
SELECT * FROM weighted;
+----+--------+
| id | weight |
+----+--------+
|  1 |      3 |
|  2 |      1 |
|  3 |      6 |
|  4 |      5 |
|  5 |     10 |
|  6 |      2 |
|  7 |      3 |
|  8 |      7 |
|  9 |      7 |
+----+--------+

So, crudely...

SELECT *,RAND()*weight FROM weighted;
+----+--------+--------------------+
| id | weight | RAND()*weight      |
+----+--------+--------------------+
|  1 |      3 | 1.7466305203238788 |
|  2 |      1 | 0.6615251914239724 |
|  3 |      6 | 3.3659728051777673 |
|  4 |      5 |  4.102008970549338 |
|  5 |     10 |  4.190225986940997 |
|  6 |      2 | 1.2678152837490806 |
|  7 |      3 |  2.737411332072142 |
|  8 |      7 |  4.624405276611824 |
|  9 |      7 | 3.9601472736896457 |
+----+--------+--------------------+

SELECT *,RAND()*weight x FROM weighted ORDER BY x DESC LIMIT 1;
+----+--------+--------------------+
| id | weight | x                  |
+----+--------+--------------------+
|  8 |      7 | 4.6799722441285585 |
+----+--------+--------------------+

SELECT *,RAND()*weight x FROM weighted ORDER BY x DESC LIMIT 1;
+----+--------+-------------------+
| id | weight | x                 |
+----+--------+-------------------+
|  9 |      7 | 5.331623214605845 |
+----+--------+-------------------+

SELECT *,RAND()*weight x FROM weighted ORDER BY x DESC LIMIT 1;
+----+--------+-------------------+
| id | weight | x                 |
+----+--------+-------------------+
|  4 |      5 | 4.931961209449881 |
+----+--------+-------------------+

SELECT *,RAND()*weight x FROM weighted ORDER BY x DESC LIMIT 1;
+----+--------+-------------------+
| id | weight | x                 |
+----+--------+-------------------+
|  8 |      7 | 6.230309537826394 |
+----+--------+-------------------+

SELECT *,RAND()*weight x FROM weighted ORDER BY x DESC LIMIT 1;
+----+--------+-------------------+
| id | weight | x                 |
+----+--------+-------------------+
|  5 |     10 | 5.470934962361059 |
+----+--------+-------------------+
```